# Unable to compile C++ code using OTLv4 library

Tags: oracle, otl

Could you help me figure out what's missing here?
I'm trying to compile a c++ program using the OTL 4 library but I'm getting an error.

Environment Details:

- I've installed Oracle DB XE 10G on an Ubuntu 11.04 VM.
- SQL*Plus and the server itself is running as it should be.

Compile code is:

```
g++ -o <output>.exe <source>.cpp -I$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public -I$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh
```

Error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libnnz10.so, needed by /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nztSetAppDefaultLocation'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nzos_DisableClientAuthentication'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nzos_Create_Ctx'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nzgbllsm_location_shared_memory'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `__intel_cpu_indicator'  
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nzosSCCS_SetCRLCacheSize'  
...a whole lot more undefined references...   
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `nzssGSL_GetSecretLength'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Notes on the error:
When I checked, the `libnnz10.so` exists when I looked into my `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out this afternoon and I got it to compile now.
So in case someone stumbles with the same problem as I did here's the solution:

Add the `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` path to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

For convenience you may also add this to your `.bashrc` profile like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That's it!

*PS:*
*I was trying to post this earlier but it seemed that I still lack in rep points*
*in order to answer my own question sooner than 8 hours.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would be necessary, but you could try just adding `-lnnz10` to your command.

(Google shows people using that extra argument, but couldn't quickly see anyone explaining why; other options seem to be to set `LD_LIBRARY` path or add `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`...)